# github clone problem (the terminal stop at 'Updating files: 100% (1015/1015), done.')

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, clone

I clone a programe form github.I write `git clone https://github.com/netwarm007/GameEngineFromScratch.git` in the terminal of vscode. It run smoothly untill `Updating files: 100% (1015/1015), done.`. I don't konw what happend and haw to finish it.

Comment: The fact that it's printed the `done` message means that it's actually finished copying all the files *out* of the commit. Why it gets stuck there is a mystery: several people on SO have reported this in the last week or so, so it may be a new bug in VS/Git interaction somehow. I think the last guy to report that said that using command-line Git worked.